# Return JSON errors in akka-http API

Tags: scala, akka-http

In an API I'm writing, I want to take and return JSON, even in cases of errors. I'm trying to figure out how to preserve all of the [`default` `RejectionHandler`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/f008a932c381013f6060ee00a731862bafed2be7/akka-http/src/main/scala/akka/http/scaladsl/server/RejectionHandler.scala#L116-L217) behavior, but convert the status codes and text into a JSON object. As the default behavior is specified within function calls, rather than as a data structure, it seems that the only way to do this is to convert the `HttpEntity` of the result it produces. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had my pieced together my own version, but it had some rough edges I didn't like. [ruslan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35165786/807674) gave me some ideas for improvement. Here's what I came up with, synthesizing the best of both approaches:

```
/**
  * Modifies the Akka-Http default rejection handler to wrap the default
  * message in JSON wrapper, preserving the original status code.
  *
  * @param rejectionWrapper wraps the message in a structure to format the
  *                         resulting JSON object
  * @param writer writer for the wrapper type
  * @tparam WrapperType type of the wrapper
  * @return the modified rejection handler
  */
def defaultRejectionHandlerAsJson[WrapperType](rejectionWrapper: String => WrapperType)(implicit writer: JsonWriter[WrapperType]) = {
  def rejectionModifier(originalMessage: String): String = {
    writer.write(rejectionWrapper(originalMessage)).prettyPrint
  }
  modifiedDefaultRejectionHandler(rejectionModifier, ContentTypes.`application/json`)
}

/**
  * Modifies the Akka-Http default rejection handler, converting the default
  * message to some other textual representation.
  *
  * @param rejectionModifier the modifier function
  * @param newContentType the new Content Type, defaulting to text/plain
  *                       UTF-8
  * @return the modified rejection handler
  */
def modifiedDefaultRejectionHandler(rejectionModifier: String => String, newContentType: ContentType.NonBinary = ContentTypes.`text/plain(UTF-8)`) = new RejectionHandler {
  def repackageRouteResult(entity: ResponseEntity): ResponseEntity = entity match {
    // If the entity isn't Strict (and it definitely will be), don't bother
    // converting, just throw an error, because something's weird.
    case strictEntity: HttpEntity.Strict =>
      val modifiedMessage = rejectionModifier(strictEntity.data.utf8String)
      HttpEntity(newContentType, modifiedMessage)
    case other =>
      throw new Exception("Unexpected entity type")
  }

  def apply(v1: Seq[Rejection]): Option[Route] = {
    // The default rejection handler should handle all possible rejections,
    // so if this isn't the case, return a 503.
    val originalResult = RejectionHandler.default(v1).getOrElse(complete(StatusCodes.InternalServerError))
    Some(mapResponseEntity(repackageRouteResult) {
      originalResult
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write something like this in your `HttpService`

```
private val defaultRejectionHandler = RejectionHandler.default

implicit def myRejectionHandler =
  RejectionHandler.newBuilder()
    .handleAll[Rejection] { rejections ⇒

    def prefixEntity(entity: ResponseEntity): ResponseEntity = entity match {
      case HttpEntity.Strict(contentType, data) => {
        import spray.json._
        val text = ErrorResponse(0, "Rejection", data.utf8String).toJson.prettyPrint
        HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/json`, text)
      }
      case _ =>
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected entity type")
    }

    mapResponseEntity(prefixEntity) {
      defaultRejectionHandler(rejections).getOrElse {
        complete(StatusCodes.InternalServerError)
      }
    }
  }.handleNotFound {
    complete(StatusCodes.Forbidden -> ErrorResponse(StatusCodes.NotFound.intValue, "NotFound", "Requested resource is not found"))
  }.result()
```

where `ErrorResponse` is possibly

```
case class ErrorResponse(error: ErrorInfo)
case class ErrorInfo(code: Int, `type`: String, message: String)
```

for which you can defined json marshallers.

Comment: Damn, that's complicated. About as complex as the way I'm solving it now. It seems like something's missing in the API that there's not an easier way.

Comment: Let me know if you find easier way :)